# How can I prompt restart in Inno Setup based off command line argument?

Tags: windows, inno-setup

There are certain cases with my application installer where I'd want to the user to restart their device. Ideally, I'd pass an arg i.e.

`Setup.exe /RESTART=yes`

And withing the setup script evaluate:

```
AlwaysRestart={param:RESTART|no}
```

Unfortunatley, that is not valid:

```
Error on ... Setup.iss: Value of [Setup] section directive "AlwaysRestart" is invalid.
Compile aborted.
```

Running InnoSetup 5.6.1

Comment: Start by taking a look at the [Scripted Constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) help topic.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I am able to pass an argument and use it in the `NeedsRestart` [event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents). This will prompt the user to restart the system at the end of a successful installation if I pass `/restart=1` as an argument.

```pascal
[Code]
function NeedRestart(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := ExpandConstant('{param:restart|0}') = '1';
end;
```